# Do a Task's continuations run async to each other?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I've searched but can't find explicit confirmation anywhere... If a Task has multiple continuations (not chained continuations), do those continuations run parallel to each other?

I want to run task1, followed by task2-task3-task4 in parallel to each other, and finally task5 when the all have finished. Example below. Will tasks 2, 3 and 4 definitely run async to each other?

While we're at it, any suggestions to improve the pattern are welcome. It seems there are several different ways to accomplish this composition. Thanks

```
public Task MyWorkflowAsync() {
  Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => DoTask1() );

  var tarray = new Task[] {
    task1.ContinueWith( task => DoTask2() ),
    task1.ContinueWith( task => DoTask3() ),
    task1.ContinueWith( task => DoTask4() )
  };

  return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll( tarray, completedTasks => DoTask5() );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, the continuations are executed in LIFO ordering by the default scheduler.  If you want them all to run in parallel, you should do this:

```
public Task MyWorkflowAsync()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(DoTask1);

    tasks.Add(task1.ContinueWith(task => tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(DoTask2))));
    tasks.Add(task1.ContinueWith(task => tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(DoTask3))));
    tasks.Add(task1.ContinueWith(task => tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(DoTask4))));

    return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), completedTasks => DoTask5());
}
```

Comment: Yuck. Not the answer I was hoping for :-) I can see why it's necessary to add the inner DoTasks, but why is it also necessary to add the outer ContinueWith tasks? In your example, tasks ends up with 6 members instead of 3, is that correct?

Comment: I'm noodling on that and you may not have to add the outers. Give it a try.

Comment: So I followed your advice and gave it a try. Looks like the pattern of my original post will give me what I need. I filled in the DoTask methods with random sleep durations, and msec-precision time stamps including their ManagedThreadID. DoTask2-4 always start within few msec of each other, in seemingly random order, on separate threads. The DoTasks finish in order of their sleep durations. Total run time is longest of 2-4, plus overhead of 1 and 5. Also, 5 always runs on same thread as the longest running of 2-4.

Comment: I believe to get the behavior Jesse describes in his post, you would need to pass TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously into Task.ContinueWith().

From the doco:

"Specifies that the continuation task should be executed synchronously. With this option specified, the continuation will be run on the same thread that causes the antecedent task to transition into its final state. If the antecedent is already complete when the continuation is created, the continuation will run on the thread creating the continuation. Only very short-running continuations should be executed synchronously."